# Objective c : can't understand how a #define macro is expanded

Tags: objective-c

Hello,

```
#define A 1+5
int a = A/A;
NSLog(@"value a %d",a);
```

it shows me the result is  11

Please can you explain me how it works? 
I want to understand the steps that the compiler does to show this result.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int a = A/A
```

is expanded into `int a = 1+5/1+5`, i.e. `1 + 5 + 5` which is 11

maybe you'd want to make it `#define A (1+5)`

Macros are not functions. They don't calculate values and insert them into the code. A macro will be simply expanded as it is written.

And btw this is not compiler who expands macros, it is the preprocessor

Comment: thank you Andrey fro your answer. However I did not understand this transition from  int a = 1+5/1+5 to  1 + 5 + 5 ?

Comment: well, maybe this will help you. 1 + 5/1 + 5 is actually 1 + (5/1) +5 as division has greater priority than addition

Comment: I see it now :) you saved my day :) thank you very much

Comment: It's just a replacement, nothing more. When using `#define` like yours, we usually tend to add extra parenthesis like `#define A (5+1)` to avoid that kind of cases.